# Android MapView path.draw draws crazy polygon lines all over the place

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, polygon

I've been struggling for a couple of weeks now with google's android mapview.

I'm drawing a large amount of polygons with a large amount of points. on average 15 polygons and around 1000 points each.

The first issue I experienced was performance... No surprise. After doing some testing I realised the culprit is projection.ToPixel() which I successfully bypass when the users pans by simply moving all my points in the direction by x amount of pixels (the difference), however when zooming I have no choice but to make use of the toPixel method.

Is there possibly a more efficient way of modifying my points depending on the zoom level? after some research I've found examples on how to do this with circles and other shapes, but I have no clue where to begin with reshaping polygons, any ideas on this?

The second issue i'm having is that when I have the entire polygon in view all is grand, but when I pan over the map bounds (where the map is effectively starting again to the left and right) on any side the polygon lines seem to reach and stretch out across the map bounds causing crazy spaghetti lines all over the place! I take it what's happening is that the path.close() or path.LineTo() methods think the shortest path is flying halfway across the world to reach the next point which causes these lines. I have no idea how to address this. I simply can't ignore points that do not fall within the current lon/lat spans because that (obviously) causes the polygon to change shape al the time!

Has anyone experienced this issue and how can one go about solving it? I'm not even sure what I should be googling!?

UPDATE 1:
The problem can be easily solved by preventing the mapview from looping. Is there some way to prevent the mapview from looping the world!?!?

Comment: UPDATE 2: I've given up on google mapview. I instead opted to create a webpage in php with google mapview (javascript version) and access it through the webview. It's faster, easier, much more powerful and more importantly much more mature.